# Using natural transform hmap with Id

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'd like to create an HMap from Class[A] to A, but I can't find a way to do this that doesn't look ugly. I've tried:

```
val defaultValues = HMap[(Class ~?> Id)#λ](
    classOf[String] -> "",
    classOf[Int] -> 0)
```

but I get a compile error because there's no implicit for Class[String], String. I can make it compile by explicitly typing the arguments using Id:

```
val defaultValues = HMap[(Class ~?> Id)#λ](
    classOf[String] -> ("": Id[String]),
    classOf[Int] -> (0: Id[Int]))
```

It's not terribly attractive though - is there a way I can do it without needing the ": Id[A]"?

Comment: An HMap is a class from the shapeless library (https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)

Answer (score 0):

HMap uses an evidence implicit to prove that you're allowed to put the key/value pair in the map. You have to encode the constraint you want in an implicit that is available when you're building the HMap or putting values into it or getting values from it.

```
import shapeless.HMap

class HMapExample {

    class InstanceOfConstraint[K, V]

    implicit def instanceOfClass[T] = new InstanceOfConstraint[Class[T], T]

    val defaultValues = HMap[InstanceOfConstraint](
      classOf[String] -> "Hello",
      classOf[Int] -> 23
    )
}
```

Should do what you need.